# i'm having a bad request 400 on a post

Tags: angular, post, ionic2, httpclient

I'm trying to make a post on my service, but I can't. When I execute the post I got a "400 bad request error".

Here is my code provider:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsuarioProvider {

  token:string;
  id_usuario:string;


  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
              private alertCrtl:AlertController) {
    console.log('Hello UsuarioProvider Provider');
  }

  ingresar( correo:string , contrasena:string){
let data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append("correo",correo);
data.append("contrasena",contrasena);

let url = URL_SERVICIOS + "/login";

return this.http.post(url,data)
        .map( (resp:any) =>{

          let data_resp = resp.json();
          console.log(data_resp);

          if( data_resp.error){
              this.alertCrtl.create({
                title: "error al iniciar",
                subTitle: data_resp.mensaje,
                buttons: ["ok"]
              }).present();
          }else{
            this.token = data_resp.token;
            this.id_usuario = data_resp.id_usuario;
          }

        });
  }

}
```

Error:

> 400 bad request error

Comment: i recommend you to first complete angular tutorial application. its gonna be helpful to learn http requests. [Angular Tutorial HTTP](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) this link navigates to tutorial's http section but i think start from the first section.

Comment: thank man i'll check it

Comment: Can you take the screen shot of error for me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Injectable()
export class UsuarioProvider {

  token:string;
  id_usuario:string;


  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
              private alertCrtl:AlertController) {
    console.log('Hello UsuarioProvider Provider');
  }

  ingresar( correo:string , contrasena:string){
let data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append("correo",correo);
data.append("contrasena",contrasena);

let url = URL_SERVICIOS + "/login";

return this.http.post(url,data)
        .subscribe( (resp: any) =>{
          console.log(resp);

          if( resp.error){
              this.alertCrtl.create({
                title: "error al iniciar",
                subTitle: resp.mensaje,
                buttons: ["ok"]
              }).present();
          }else{
            this.token = resp.token;
            this.id_usuario = resp.id_usuario;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

With HttpClient you don't need parse your response.

Comment: thank you my friend, i already fix it, i'm new in stack, it´s a lovely place